# Magento 2 cron job catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize

Tags: cron, attributes, magento2, product

I am trying to work out what the cron job "catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize" actually does.

It seems to run the following class: "WebsiteAttributesSynchronizer"
Doing some sync work with the following tables:

```
private $tableMetaDataClass = [
    'catalog_category_entity_datetime' => CategoryInterface::class,
    'catalog_category_entity_decimal' => CategoryInterface::class,
    'catalog_category_entity_int' => CategoryInterface::class,
    'catalog_category_entity_text' => CategoryInterface::class,
    'catalog_category_entity_varchar' => CategoryInterface::class,

    'catalog_product_entity_datetime' => ProductInterface::class,
    'catalog_product_entity_decimal' => ProductInterface::class,
    'catalog_product_entity_int' => ProductInterface::class,
    'catalog_product_entity_text' => ProductInterface::class,
    'catalog_product_entity_varchar' => ProductInterface::class,
];
```

I have an issue where some product data is being reverted, if I try change a product attribute value direct in the database (updating a value in the table "catalog_product_entity_datetime", after an hour or so, the value reverts). So would like to know if it may be something to do with this CRON task.

If anyone has any suggestions as to why a product attribute value changed direct in the database would revert back, I would appreciate a comment. This suggest the old product value was saved somewhere...and updated by some task after a period of time.

I have tried disabling various integrations to rule them out one by one, incase one of these services was the cause. But the services/actions these integrations provide/perform should not be related. Clutching at straws right now.

Comment: The values just reverted again, the only CRON job that seems to have run that is relevant is the one mentioned in the post.